# How do I create a portable local database using in-browser Javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, local

Can you create, write to and access a local database using in-browser Javascript? I want the local database to be saved as a file and available for all users.

Comment: *…in the browser?* Or in something like node?

Comment: In the browser.

Comment: Then no, you won't be able to write to a file on disk automatically. The best you can do is offer it for "download".

Comment: " available for all users", as in users that are not local?

Comment: Yeah. I mean, ideally, the database should be a local file that would be accessed when the site is hosted. So the users accessing the site can get the updates whenever I change the contents of the database.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but wouldn't you be able to use sqlite and do AJAX calls to the files?

Comment: I don't think so.